# Proof of continuity in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

[image]

My first attempt:

Let $U \subset Y$ be an open set. Then since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Now, if $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ then $x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$ for all $n\geq N_1$

Furthermore, $ f(x_n)\in U$ for all $n\geq N_2$

We can choose $N=\text{ max }\{N_1,N_2\}$ such that $x_n\inf^{-1}(U)$ and $f(x_n)\in U$. So $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$

Would this be correct? I'm not sure whether the thing where I introduced $N_1,N_2$ is neccessary.

Comment: You need to think a bit more about the structure of what you are trying to prove.  Remember the definition of $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$: for each neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$, $f(x_n)$ is eventually in that neighborhood.  So starting by "Let $U \subset Y$ be an open set" is not correct, because you're not proving anything about arbitrary open sets.  From the definition of $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$, you should automatically write down: "Let $U$ be an open set with $f(x) \in U$".  Then show that there is $N$ large enough so that $n > N$ implies $f(x_n) \in U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ means proving that, for each neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies f(x_n)\in V$. I did not see you proving this.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $V$ such that $f(x)\in U$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$. Besides, since $f(x)\in U$, $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. So, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies x_n\in f^{-1}(U)$. And therefore$$n\geqslant N\implies f(x_n)\in U\implies f(x_n)\in V.$$

Comment: Could you actually clarify, why is it necessary to write that part with $V$? Couldn't we be fine with just proving $f(x_n) \in U \Rightarrow f(x_n) \to f(x)$?

Comment: I used this definition of limit of a sequence: $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n =x$ if, for every neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies x_n\in V.$$

Comment: ok, thank you, i see now